# Problem running pdf2text jar. File not found exception

Tags: java, apache, filenotfoundexception

I have been trying to run the pdf2text tool provided by apache. I initially got the 'failed to load main-class manifest attribute' error. So I modified the manifest file in the jar to include the Main-Class attribute. Wrote it as -

```
Main-Class: org.apache.pdfbox.ExtractText
```

But after this, I am getting the exception -

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
        org.apache.pdfbox.ExtractText (No such file or directory)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:106)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:66)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.load(PDDocument.java:978)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.ExtractText.startExtraction(ExtractText.java:196)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.ExtractText.main(ExtractText.java:76)
```

What can possibly be the mistake here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to switch to this entry point (Main-class):

```
org.apache.pdfbox.PDFBox
```

edit: this setup should also work (if you want to extract text)

```
java -cp ./pdfbox-1.6.0.jar org.apache.pdfbox.PDFBox ExtractText some.pdf
```

**note** that you need to add Apache's logging package and so on to your CLASSPATH variable, unless you set that at the command line as well..